# HttpCompileException, CS024 Namespace Could Not Be Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

When running my project I get a "HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code" message. I have looked at all these site questions similar with this problem, but none of the solutions have worked.

I have tried:

- Restarting my computer.
- Changed the Assembly type to .NET Framework 4 on all my projects
- I have remade my projects

When Running it it returns with an error code of: **CS0246**.

Everything is coded in **C# ASP.NET MVC3**. I have a partial view that I am trying to pass information from my Service Layer. It is nested in my Shared Layout partial that gives my site structure. I new up an object where I call my partial:

```
@Html.Partial("Profile", new UserService())
```

Well the error does not get thrown on this code but the Grandparent class of where this is coded.I assumed that I needed to add my using statement in all the partials that parent the current partial. That did not work but throw the same error except on where I placed the Using statement.

```
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass8.<FindPartialView>b__7(IViewEngine e)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext, String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Azurix\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\rizowski.net\Rizowski\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 22
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

I have spent a lot of time with this error. And everywhere I look, it is not the answer to my question. Any other Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: could you please show the stack trace?

Comment: @Anwar I have provided the Stack Trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your Razor view knows nothing about the `UserService` class that you are trying to use. Make sure you have added the namespace in which this class is defined on the top of your view:

```
@using AppName.Models
...
@Html.Partial("Profile", new UserService())
```

or fully qualify it:

```
@Html.Partial("Profile", new AppName.Models.UserService())
```

or add it to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file (recommended as now this type will be available to all Razor views):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="AppName.Models" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have sent me your VS2010 solution by mail I see what your problem is. Both your `Rizowski.Services` and `Data.Rizowski` projects are Console Applications. You should convert them to Class libraries. Right click on each of them and in the properties change the Output Type to `Class Library`:

[image]

Comment: I got this after fully Qualifying the class:
'{"c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\5343a94a\\6a35728a\\App_Web__logonpartial.cshtml.639c3968.jonxdghm.0.cs(27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Services' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"}'

Comment: @Rizowski, is this class defined in a separate project/assembly? Have you referenced this assembly in your ASP.NET MVC application? Did you ensure that the namespace is correct?

Comment: I have a Service Project MVC project and my Data Project. They are all separated from each other. I have deleted the reference, re-added the reference and double checked the name. It is all correct. Could it be that my Service project is called "Service.OtherName" ?

Comment: @Rizowski, no idea what could it be. 3 possibilities: 1. the project is not referenced. 2. The namespace you used is wrong. 3. The `UserService` type that you are trying to access is not public.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do, Because I keep remaking the projects only to get the same error.

Comment: @Rizowski, if you are not sure, I am even less sure as I don't know what you have so far. Maybe if you could send me a VS2010 solution with your project I can take a look at it and tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Oh I found out how to contact you.

Comment: @Rizowski, you could send it by email. Click on my profile to see my mail.

Comment: I sent the Email. The issue is in my Service project and my MVC project. My MVC project under _Layout is where it is throwing the error.

Comment: @Rizowski, you are using Console Application as output type to your projects. You need to change this to `Class Library`. I have updated my answer to illustrate you how to do that by right clicking on the `Rizowski.Services` and `Data.Rizowski` projects and changing their type.